# Create an APK that will install additional components for my app

Tags: android, apk

I would like to separate my Android Java application from codec pack (a .so library), to be distributed separately **as .apk** (the main app doesn't require these codecs to work properly + there's licence clash). How do I do such thing? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many game developers do the following for .so and graphics data.
I am assuming you are familiar with NDK.

1. your app needs access to the SD
2. Once User installs your app start downloading your .so files into a location on the sdcard
3. load your .so dynamically and make call to the functions you require

Comment: OK, that's some kind of solution, but what I really wanted was an additional apk. I'll update my question.

Comment: additional apk? why I mean if apk then just put the libs into the main apk. The best approach is to zip all your images and libs and download them after user installs your main apk which should stay small so users install it easier.